# reading file php

Tags: php, file-io

The file I'm using to read has a lot of tabs and when I echo using nlb12, it doesn't output the  tab space. Does anyone know if there's a way to keep the tab space when you're outputting file contents?

Comment: wrap the output in <pre> tags

Comment: Also be sure to not have trim function.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the output in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Output it in `<pre>` tabs

`echo "<pre>" . nl2br($content) . "</pre>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($MyVariable, true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the file in a browser?
Then you have to use `<pre><?php echo $line;?></pre>`